# js change dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

First 3 dropdown lists are working. If you click add lecture button, it adds 3 dropdown more. I want to create same dropdowns with add lecture button but course list does not appear in additional dropdowns. If the subject is cs, the course dropdown should show 307 and 306 or if the subject is ie, the course dropdown should show 208, 301. Grade dropdown always same and it is working everywhere.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOXMJb?editors=1010

html

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="add-field">Add Lecture</button>        
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">

            <select class="text-two" name="attraction_or_activity[]">
                <option value="attraction_or_activity">subject</option>
                <option value="cs">CS</option>
      <option value="ie">IE</option>
                <option value="math">MATH</option>
            </select>
            <!--input id="attr_acti_btn" type="button" value="Click to Show!" /-->

            <select id="populated_attr_or_activity" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]">
                <!-- here I ahve to populate the ARRAYS as option -->
                <option value="available_attr_act">course</option>
            </select>

    <select class="text-one" name="destination[]">
                <option selected value="base">grade</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
      <option value="f">F</option>
            </select>

        </div>
            <br/>
            <!--div id="myDiv"></div>
            <div id="attr_or_act_div"></div>

          <!--a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a-->

    </div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".text-two").change(function() { // when the attraction_OR_activity dropdown is selected
$('#populated_attr_or_activity').html(''); // emptying the selections of 3rd dropdown list if there was any selections were made before.

    /* saving selected values in variables */
    var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
    var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

    colombo_attractions = new Array("307","306");
    colombo_activities = new Array("208","301");
        colombo_act = new Array("203","306");

    if ( selected_attraction_or_activity == 'cs') {
        colombo_attractions.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if ( selected_attraction_or_activity == 'ie') {
        colombo_activities.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

if ( selected_attraction_or_activity == 'math') {
        colombo_activities.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }


});

/* ADD DESTINATION */
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    var x = 1;
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        x++;
            $($wrapper).append('<div class="multi-field"><select class="text-two'+x+'" name="attraction_or_activity[]"><option selected value="attraction_or_activity">subject</option><option value="cs">CS</option><option value="ie">IE</option><option value="math">MATH</option></select><select id="populated_attr_or_activity'+x+'"name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]"><option value="available_attr_act">course</option></select><select id="populated_attr_or_activity'+x+'" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]"><option value="available_attr_act">grade</option><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option><option value="c">C</option><option value="d">D</option><option value="f">F</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    });

    $($wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});});
```

Comment: some error in the pen u submitted

Comment: can u help me about this situation

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you:

```js
function ProcessData(subject) {
        var course =  $(subject).parent().find("[name='attraction_or_activity_selected[]']")
        var grade = $(subject).parent().find("[name='destination[]']")
        
        $(course).val('');
        var selected_grade = $(grade).val();
        var selected_subject =  $(subject).val();
        /* saving selected values in variables */
        //var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
        //var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

        colombo_attractions = new Array("307", "306");
        colombo_activities = new Array("208", "301");
        colombo_act = new Array("203", "306");
        
        $(course).find('option').not(':first').remove();
        if (selected_subject == 'cs') {
            colombo_attractions.forEach(function (t) {
                $(course).append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }

        if (selected_subject == 'ie') {
            colombo_activities.forEach(function (t) {
                $(course).append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }

        if (selected_subject == 'math') {
            colombo_activities.forEach(function (t) {
                $(course).append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".text-two").change(function () { // when the attraction_OR_activity dropdown is selected
            ProcessData($(this));
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        /* ADD DESTINATION */
        $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function () {
            var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
            var x = 1;
            $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
                x++;
                $($wrapper).append('<div class="multi-field"><select class="text-two' + x + '" name="attraction_or_activity[]"><option selected value="attraction_or_activity">subject</option><option value="cs">CS</option><option value="ie">IE</option><option value="math">MATH</option></select><select id="populated_attr_or_activity' + x + '"name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]"><option value="available_attr_act">course</option></select><select name="destination[]"><option value="available_attr_act">grade</option><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option><option value="c">C</option><option value="d">D</option><option value="f">F</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                $($wrapper).on("change", ".text-two" + x, function (e) { //user click on remove text
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ProcessData($(this));
                })
            });

            $($wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="add-field">Add Lecture</button>
    <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">

            <select class="text-two" name="attraction_or_activity[]">
                <option value="attraction_or_activity">subject</option>
                <option value="cs">CS</option>
                <option value="ie">IE</option>
                <option value="math">MATH</option>
            </select>
            <!--input id="attr_acti_btn" type="button" value="Click to Show!" /-->

            <select id="populated_attr_or_activity" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]">
                <!-- here I ahve to populate the ARRAYS as option -->
                <option value="available_attr_act">course</option>
            </select>

            <select class="text-one" name="destination[]">
                <option selected=selected value="base">grade</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
                <option value="d">D</option>
                <option value="f">F</option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <br />
        <!--div id="myDiv"></div>
          <div id="attr_or_act_div"></div>

        <!--a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a-->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is roughly working but  if i select a subject and change same dropbox with another subject, it adds up add on.

Comment: made correction to clear data if option is changing,Try now.